# Image in header not show when go to another page in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

My header homepage has logo image with site_url but when I move to another page the header with Image is error but the link still work. I check Inspect homepage which show image link is " xxx.local/xx.png but I check Inspect in another page that show the image link is xxx.local/about/xx.png.

```
<nav>
  <a class="school-logo-text float-left"><a href="<?php echo site_url() ?>"><img src="xxx.png" style="width:`enter code here`215px;height:141px;></a></a>
      </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your function file.

```
register_default_headers( array(
'default-image' => array(
    'url'           => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/default-header.jpg',
    'thumbnail_url' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/img/default-header.jpg',
    'description'   => __( 'Default Header Image', 'textdomain' )
),
) );
```

Try to upload your image.
See this for more details https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_default_headers.

Comment: it work but that is another code in the link you send me. Anyways, thanks so much

Comment: the link is just for you reference